# I need read a dir with filter using fs library

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

I am reading a directory with several files and need to filter according to the last modified date.

I tried to get the file status after reading the directory, but it take too long

```
const files = fs.readdirSync(params.pathDirectory, { encoding: 'utf8' });

console.log('Files to search', files);
params.files = files;
return params;
```

I tried to read after having all the files, but it takes too long

```
let stat = fs.statSync(`${params.pathDirectory}/${nameFile}`);
```

So i need a method to filter this file during the `readdir` method. For Example a callback.

How can i do this?

Comment: The `*Sync` methods are synchronous and should not be `await`ed.

Comment: if on a stable known environ, you might use command line tools to quickly pre-filter your input. For example, list sorted by date and tail'ed to grab the 10 most recent files.

Comment: @SLaks Thx for that observation

Comment: @dandavis it's a good idea, but my connection with server is slowly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [klaw](https://github.com/jprichardson/node-klaw) for async or [klaw-sync](https://github.com/manidlou/node-klaw-sync) for sync usage:

```
const klawSync = require('klaw-sync')

const refTime = new Date(2017, 3, 24).getTime()
const filterFn = item => item.stats.mtime.getTime() > refTime

const files = klawSync(params.pathDirectory, { nodir: true, filter: filterFn })
```